# returns Damaged frame

Tags: opencv, emgucv

this is my code:

```
Capture cap = new Capture("rtsp://192.168.226.201:554/profile1");
fps = (int)cap.GetCaptureProperty(CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
Application.Idle += process;
private void process(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frame = cap.QueryFrame();
    if (frame == null)
        return;
    imageBox1.Image = frame;
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 /fps);
}
```

This code works correctly
But after a few seconds returns Damaged frame
like this:
http://www.quranmp3.ir/images/1/1111.jpg

The question is:
What is your solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One fix to be this problem could be to force the RTSP protocol to use TCP (instead of the UDP) as a transport. you can append `?tcp` into your URL e.g. `rtsp://192.168.226.201:554/profile1?tcp` then pass it to `open()` method.

Comment: sorry can you Explain more